# How to open bootstrap modal using a button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have developed a simple js pig game. You can see it here: http://creativeartbd.com/demo/game/js-pig-game

At first, it will open a Bootstrap Modal box to set a winning score. Now, the game will begin by click on the Roll Dice button.

Well, now if you WIN then you can press the New Game button to re-play the game. Here, I want to open the bootstrap modal again when I click on the New Game button.  For that I have write this code:

```
document.querySelector(".btn-new-game").addEventListener("click", function () {
    init();     
    document.getElementById("myModal").modal('show');       
});
```

but it's showing me an error message on console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).modal is not a function
```

Maybe this is because of Javascript IIFE. I don't know exactly :(

I have also tried with this code:

```
document.getElementById("myModal").click();
```

but no luck :(

My HTML and js code is a bit long that's why I don't put here. You can find it here: https://jsfiddle.net/r8cga7L5/

Thanks.

Comment: `$("#myModal").modal('show');`

Comment: you can use `$("#myModal").modal('open');`  `$("#myModal").modal('show');`  `$("#myModal").modal('toggle');`

Comment: then its showing this error: bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: f[b] is not a function

Comment: You already using model on window load using Jquery the same way you can open model on button click also.
`document.querySelector(".btn-new-game").addEventListener("click", function () {
  init();  
  $('#myModal').modal('show');
 });`

Comment: Sorry i dont have enough access to your link.. @creativeartbd

Comment: please check this fiddle with what i have added the same code of yours like `$('#myModal').modal('show');` and its working  -- https://jsfiddle.net/z12uL3ba/

Comment: let me check it.

Comment: @Sethuraman it seems working :)

Answer (score 3):

Modify the button like this,
It's working perfectly fine

```
<button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btn btn-new-game">New Game(+)</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any specific reason you want the modal to open from JS?

Try this for the Bootstrap 4 approach:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can just call it like this:

`document.getElementById("myModal").modal();`

Comment: Then it's showing me: TypeError: document.getElementById(...).modal is not a function